# Datetimepicker time and date conversion

Tags: php, mysql, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I've been trying for hours to change the format of my datetimepicker (Tempus DOminus for bootstrap 4) but the format won't change so now I'm trying to find a better way to convert it on the backend when it inserts to my database.

The issue is, the datetimepicker currently puts the user selected date into the input as

```
10/02/2018 2:15 PM
```

The problem is, I need to insert it into the database like so:

```
2018-10-02 02:15:00
```

Is there a better way that I can just auto convert that to fit the mysql timestamp format I need?

I'm thinking there would have to be a way for me to look at the AM/PM from the datetimepicker and make it either 02:00:00 or 14:00:00 accordingly.

I can convert the date by doing date('Y-m-d') but I don't know how to do the full thing.

Since I'm having issues with the actual picker format, can anyone help me convert this properly?

Comment: suggest you include the php you are using to handle the value returned by your datepicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to parse the date format you are getting from your datepicker:

```
$datestr = '10/02/2018 2:15 PM';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y h:i A', $datestr);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Output:

```
2018-10-02 14:15:00
```